# Crash self-taught course in microeconomics for exam (bib recommendation)

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request

I'm going to present a test in microeconomics that will cover topics up to *undergraduate* level, and I need some recommendation in which bibliography and sequence to pick in the interest of time efficiency:

- I need to refresh topics related to:

  - Basics of consumer theory.
  - Basics of producer theory.
  - Elasticities.
  - Slutsky equation.
  - Perfect competition.
  - Partial (and a bit of general) equilibrium.
  - Monopoly (optimization, price discrimination, exit decision, relations between costs, production func. and demand).

Yet I have not found any practical route of resources to follow.

- Regardless of the book, what I need is a sequence of chapters that gives me a broad refresh that I can study in two weeks or less, i.e., I prefer it very condensed and cut to the chase.
- I prefer books that emphasize the math and the general, rather than plotting too many curves focusing on particulars (of course with this I don't mean I need to go as advanced as analysis-based proofs like Mas-Colell).

If someone may help, I'd be very grateful.

PD: I have already passed those courses a couple years ago, just need a refresh.

Comment: There is no global standard of what "microeconomics I and II" should cover and mean. You need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Just updated the question based on your comment. Thanks!

Comment: I would probably go with Varian's Intermediate Microeconomics: https://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/microeco-_varian.pdf. It's a bit more formal than my other choice, the Pindyck/Rubinfeld.